# Find the node with given value in binary tree in in-order way and return it

Tags: java, search, binary-tree

find the node in binary tree in inorder way, and return it
PS： the binary tree may include two nodes with the same value.
it's easy to do it in pre-order way

```
Node find(Node root, int val){...}
```

anyone can share a solution?

Comment: @smk i tried to solve it recursively, once I find the node how to stop and return it
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Havent tested it out thoroughly but this code should work.

```
public TreeNode find(TreeNode cur,int val) {

        TreeNode result = null;
        if(cur.left != null)
            result = find(cur.left,val);


        if(cur.value == val)
            return cur;
        if(result ==null && cur.right != null)
            result = find(cur.right,val);

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: thanks   a little modify before cur.value==val  u also need to check if result==null